# Speed Powershell Script Up

Tags: powershell

I am looking for way to speed up my Powershell script.  I have a script that returns the manager Employee ID and manager name based on a .txt file that has the samaccountnames for each user under that manager.  The problem is the list is very long, about 1400+ names and the script is taking forever to run.    Here is my script. It works, just looking for a way to speed it up:

```
cls
If (!(Get-Module -Name activerolesmanagementshell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
Import-Module activerolesmanagementshell
}
Write-host $("*" * 75)
Write-host "*"
Write-host "*    Input file should contain just a list of samaccountnames - no header row."
Write-host "*"
Write-host $("*" * 75)

$File = Read-Host -Prompt "Please supply a file name"

If (!(test-path $File))
{
Write-host "Sorry couldn't find the file...buh bye`n`n"
exit
}

get-content $File | %{

$EmpInfo = get-qaduser -proxy -Identity $_ -IncludedProperties employeeid,edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID

# Check if we received back a Manager ID - if yes, get the Manager's name
# If not, set the Manager Name to "NONE" for output

If ($($EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID).length -gt 2)
{

# Get the Manager's name from AD
$($EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID)

$ManagerName = $(Get-QADUser -SearchAttributes @{employeeid=$($EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID)} | select name).name

If (!$ManagerName)
{
$ManagerName = "NONE"
}

# Add the Manager name determined above (or NONE) to the properties we'll eventually output

$EmpInfo | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ManagerName -Value $ManagerName

}
Else
{
$EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID = "NONE"
}

# Output user samaccountname edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID and ManagerName to a file

$EmpInfo | select samaccountname,edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID,ManagerName | export-csv "C:\Users\sfp01\Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\Script_DisaUser_MgrEmpID\Disabled_Users_With_Manager.txt" -NoTypeInformation -Append

}  # End of file processing loop
```

Comment: This is much better suited for Stack Exchange's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site than StackOverflow in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first... asking your user to type in a file name. Give them a nice friendly dialog box with little effort. Here's a function I keep on hand:

```
Function Get-FilePath{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Comma Seperated Values (*.csv)|*.csv|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = $home,
    [String]$Title)

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    $OpenFileDialog.Title = $Title
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$File = Get-FilePath -Filter 'Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*' -InitialDirectory "$home\Desktop" -Title 'Select user list'
```

That doesn't speed things up, it's just a quality of life improvement.

Secondly, your 'can't find the file' message will appear as the window closes, so the person that ran your script probably won't see it. Towards that end I have a function that I use to pause a script with a message.

```
Function Invoke-Pause ($Text){
    [reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Windows.Forms')|out-null
    If($psISE){
        [Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$Text", "Script Paused", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]"OK", [Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]"Information") | ?{(!($_ -eq "OK"))}
    }Else{
        Write-Host $Text
        Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
        $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
    }
}
```

With that you can get a message to the user, and then close the script so the user knows what happened. This function works in both the PowerShell console, as well as in the PowerShell ISE. In the console you get a text message that you define, and then a 'Press any key to continue...' message, and it waits for the user to press a key. In the ISE it pops up a window with your message, and waits for the user to click the OK button before proceeding. You could do something like:

```
If(!(Test-Path $File)){Invoke-Pause "Sorry couldn't find the file...buh bye";exit}
```

Now to get on to speeding things up!

You have more than one employee per manager right? So why look up the manager more than once? Setup a hashtable to keep track of your manager info, and then only look them up if you can't find them in the hashtable. Before your loop declare `$Managers` as a hashtable that just declares that 'NONE' = 'NONE', then inside the loop populate it as needed, and then reference it later.

Also, you are appending to a file for each user. That means PowerShell has to get a file lock on the file, write to it, close the file, and release the lock on it... over and over and over and over... Just pipe your users down the pipeline and write to the file once at the end.

```
Function Get-FilePath{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [String]$Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Comma Seperated Values (*.csv)|*.csv|Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt",
    [String]$InitialDirectory = $home,
    [String]$Title)

    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $InitialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.filter = $Filter
    $OpenFileDialog.Title = $Title
    [void]$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

cls
If (!(Get-Module -Name activerolesmanagementshell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
{
Import-Module activerolesmanagementshell
}
Write-host $("*" * 75)
Write-host "*"
Write-host "*    Input file should contain just a list of samaccountnames - no header row."
Write-host "*"
Write-host $("*" * 75)

$File = Get-FilePath -Filter 'Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*' -InitialDirectory "$home\Desktop" -Title 'Select user list'

If (!(test-path $File))
{
Write-host "Sorry couldn't find the file...buh bye`n`n"
exit
}

$Managers = @{'NONE'='NONE'}
Get-Content $File | %{
    $EmpInfo = get-qaduser -proxy -Identity $_ -IncludedProperties employeeid,edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID
    Switch($EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID){
        {$_.Length -lt 2} {$EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID = 'NONE'}
        {$_ -notin $Managers.Keys} {
            $MgrLookup = Get-QADUser -SearchAttributes @{employeeid=$EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID} |% Name
            If(!$MgrLookup){$MgrLookup = 'NONE'}
            $Managers.add($EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID,$MgrLookup)
            }
    }
    Add-Member -InputObject $EmpInfo -NotePropertyName 'ManagerName' -NotePropertyValue $Managers[$EmpInfo.edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID] -PassThru
} | select samaccountname,edsva_SSCOOP_managerEmployeeID,ManagerName | Export-Csv "C:\Users\sfp01\Documents\Data_Deletion_Testing\Script_DisaUser_MgrEmpID\Disabled_Users_With_Manager.txt" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```